# Print Setup dialog in .NET

Tags: .net, printing, dialog

Is there a .NET wrapper for the standard *Print Setup* dialog (**not** the *Print* dialog)? I see there is `System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog` which is roughly equivalent to `CPrintDialog` but it seems there is no way to set the `PD_PRINTSETUP` flag for it.

Comment: PrintDialog actually *is* a wrapper of the native print dialog.  Just like CPrintDialog is a wrapper.  There's only one native dialog.

Comment: But it doesn't support all the flags which CPrintDialog supports, does it?

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for [`PageSetupDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.pagesetupdialog.aspx).

Comment: I don't think so. Although there is the `AllowPrinter` property in `PageSetupDialog`, it is marked as obsolete and doesn't work in Vista/Win7. Actually, I am looking for the dialog that is shown in the `CWinApp::OnFilePrintSetup` MFC method.